# Why are Daleks terrifying?

Tags: doctor-who, dalek

I'm fairly new to Dr. Who, just having watched some of the newer episodes, and find Daleks rather, well, odd. The idea seems to be that they probably are cheesy villains by today's standards but weren't in the 1960s, and given that modern Dr. Who does have some [really](http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m2rysf3Pyw1qd2wc8.jpg) [terrifying](http://www.themarysue.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/1213553-weeping_angel.jpg) monsters, [they are a bit out of place](http://punch.photoshelter.com/image/I0000ZvleumhOmDo).

Still, even in-universe it's hard to glean their terror. They seem slow and dumb. Perhaps they're durable but maybe you can tip them over or something. In the scenes I've watched with Daleks the show of course takes it for granted that you, the viewer, are terrified. So, why should I be?

Comment: http://punch.photoshelter.com/image/I0000ZvleumhOmDo

Comment: @Fruitbat exactly! edited in to question.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BdQ7RcfnMOU

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xO7CwDkvDEw

Comment: [*Exterminate!*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mxD-5z_xHBU) - Kinda freaky, no?

Comment: -1 since it seems as though the OP is asking for an opinion "Why should I be?" If a high rep user can explain why I am wrong though I will gladly remove the vote.

Comment: They're modeled after national socialists, and designed to be as non-humanoid as possible. One arm for saluting, one arm for a gun.

Comment: @GhostKoi the series pretty firmly establishes that the Daleks *are* terrifying - dramatic music, lots of closeups, cliffhangers right around the 40-minute mark in a TV show, the sweat on The Doctor's brow. I just don't know why a bunch of garbage cans warrant dramatic music, closeups, cliffhangers, and Doctor sweat. I couldn't care less whether The Internet thinks I should sleep with an eye open tonight because a Dalek might get me.

Comment: @GhostKoi and being new to the series I've likely missed a lot of episodes that in-universe explain why the Daleks are terrifying, although I have out-of-universe reasons to believe the in-universe reasons exist. Hence this question.

Comment: The fact that Daleks are kind of funny in an out-of-universe sense yet we accept that everyone finds them terrifying in-universe is part of the appeal, I think. That said, the episode "Dalek" from the first season of the revived series did a pretty good job at helping viewers suspend disbelief about them being a serious threat to the characters, even if they're still kind of funny-looking.

Answer (score 24):

Assuming we are talking about modern Daleks (thus no need to worry about stairs and such):

1. Nigh invulnerability. Seriously, everything thrown at them more or less bounces without a scratch.
2. Very deadly. Everything from life forms to complex machinery are ground under their treads completely effortlessly.
3. Absolutely evil. Emotions like love and empathy have been purged from their race. They exist only to sterilize the entire time stream of any non-Dalek life. They can't be reasoned with or argued with, they have no interest in any non-Daleks supremacy related issues whatsoever.
4. Their voices. They're freaky and shrill.
5. Intelligent. The Daleks are incredibly intelligent and have access to some of the most sophisticated technology that exists. With this intelligence also comes patience- they are absolutely willing to set something in motion now according to their calculations which will result in their victory in five hundred years.

Comment: Hands down, #4.

Comment: #5 is very interesting and certainly not something you glean from screenshots and the like.

Comment: @Mazura : **"EX-TER-MIN-ATE!"**

Comment: @djechlin it's not evident in every episode either but it's quite true. The Time War the Doctor refers to? That's between the Time Lords and the Daleks. And the Time Lords aren't the ones still running around causing trouble (as of the last time I watched when the Ponds stopped being on).

Comment: Just as an aside, even in classic Who, Daleks are shown navigating stairs, specifically in the 7th Doctor story *Resurrection of the Daleks*.

Comment: The Doctor has escaped the Daleks via the dreaded stairs on more than one occasion. They even allude to it with the Eccleston Doctor when they climb some stairs and he laughs that the Dalek can't reach them, before the Dalek engages it's hover mechanism.

Comment: @djechlin is there something else you're looking for to declare an answer?

Answer (score 14):

If you haven't watched Series 1 Episode titled "Dalek", you should. I think it does a brilliant job on establishing the Daleks' nature and role in the Whoniverse.

The first time the character Van Statten finds the Dalek, he's not scared by it. The same for his whole staff, or even Rose. It isn't until the Dalek breaks free, and starts killing everything it finds that they start to realize the destruction machine that they had all along

It is further explained with this dialogue.

> VAN STATTEN: I thought you were the great expert, Doctor. If you're so impressive, then why not just reason with this Dalek? It must be willing to negotiate. There must be something it needs. Everything needs something.
>
> DOCTOR: What's the nearest town?
>
> VAN STATTEN: Salt Lake City.
>
> DOCTOR: Population?
>
> VAN STATTEN: One million.
>
> DOCTOR: All dead. If the Dalek gets out, it'll murder every living creature. That's all it needs.
>
> VAN STATTEN: But why would it do that?
>
> DOCTOR: Because it honestly believes they should die.

As usual, evil lies in the eyes of the beholder. They don't see themselves as evil, maybe as the opposite. They honestly believe they should kill any creature that is not a Dalek.